# Why does it not show a horizontal line between brackets with color in VSCode bracket colorizer?

Tags: vscode-extensions, brackets, vs-code-settings

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
"cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
"editor.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Light'",
"editor.lineHeight": 30,
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.activeScopeCSS": [
    "borderStyle : solid",
    "borderWidth : 1px",
    "borderColor : {color}",
    "opacity: 0.5"
],
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.showHorizontalScopeLine": true
```

This is what is written in my `settings.json` but still it is not showing a horizontal line between brackets with color.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have tried your settings, and I found that the extension that you are using, `Bracket Pair Colorizer 2`, is currently deprecated because it is built-in now to VSCode. Therefore it might get disabled/uninstalled. If you stil want to show a horizontal line between brackets with color, you can install that extension and try again. I think it works.

This is what on my computer after installing the extension:
[image]